# PhantomJS stops screen capture on js error, but page renders fine in browser

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

How can I make PhantomJS continue to screen capture after encountering a JS error on the page? The page renders correctly in browsers, just not in PhantomJS screen capture.

**1 page works, 1 page fails:**

PhantomJS fails to capture the graph on this page: https://www.graf.ly/user_graphs/510.

PhantomJS is successful on this page: https://www.graf.ly/user_graphs/505.

**Error:**

It seems that PhantomJS encounters errors on the page and stops capturing. I run the [rasterize.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) script from [PhantomJS's tutorial](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) with debug mode on I get this error on the failed page:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'function(e){this.visible=true;this.update(e)}.bind(this)')

  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rickshaw/1.4.6/rickshaw.min.js:2
  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rickshaw/1.4.6/rickshaw.min.js:2
  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rickshaw/1.4.6/rickshaw.min.js:1 in klass
  https://www.graf.ly/graph_templates/55/graph.js:278
  https://www.graf.ly/graph_templates/55/graph.js:11
  https://www.graf.ly/graph_templates/55/index.html?dataset=1208&options=2140:177 in ready
  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/queue-async/1.0.7/queue.min.js:1 in o
  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/queue-async/1.0.7/queue.min.js:1
  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.2/d3.min.js:1
  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.2/d3.min.js:1 in t
  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.2/d3.min.js:1 in u
```

Comment: Why don't you fix the JS error? If you're expecting the JS error, when wrap it in a try/catch. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502899/how-do-i-capture-javascript-errors-generated-in-a-page-fetched-by-phantomjs.

Comment: It's user contributed code, so this still needs to be as robust as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception means that phantomjs' JS engine does not support `bind` function. Try to include  (directly in html page or through phantomjs script using [includeJs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/include-js.html) or [injectJs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/inject-js.html) functions) some polyfill like [the one on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim), etc...

Comment: If you go to PhantomJS's repo, and look at issues, there is a very recent post with code that worked. The older shims did not work for me.